# Kendo subgrid deletion (with php)

Tags: php, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I use example like this:[Tutorial for Kendo and PHP](http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/PHP/build-apps-with-kendo-ui-and-php)

And I use code in subgrid as in grid:

```
subDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: "data/channelName.php?acc="+e.data.userId,
            destroy: {
                url: "data/chMove.php",
                type: "DELETE",
                complete: function (e) {
                    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert(e.responseText);
        },
        schema: {
            data: "results",
            model: {
                id: "channelId"
            }
        }
    });
detailRow.find(".subgrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: subDS,
        columns: [
                { 
                    title: "Channel Name", field: "channelname" 
                },
                { 
                    command: ["destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "100px" 
                }]
    });
```

However, the code isn't fired in server side of PHP code,

I not sure it is client side code wrong or server side?

The read is return:

{"results":[{"channelname":"test"},{"channelname":"5413trret"},{"channelname":"d453"},{"channelname":"test3"},{"channelname":"ter"},{"channelname":"test5"}]}

and userId is in the read of the grid.

The server side(chMove.php) I try to test if it is fired use alert like:

```
<?php

    // determine the request type
    $verb = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];

    echo "<script>alert('"."123"."');</script>";

?>
```

But the alert never be fired, needless to say I want to get the `parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $request );`
later and parse the $request.

The final goal is delete what user click in the "Delete" button and the server side can delete it in database.

Any idea about my code?
Or is there any other method to do deletion of subgrid?

Any advice appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have alternate method.
I look the manual : [Below show how to fired remove function](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.command.click)

And the code is like:

```
var detailRow = e.detailRow;
    subDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: "data/channelName.php?acc="+e.data.userId
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert(e.responseText);
        },
        schema: {
            data: "results",
            model: {
                id: "channelid",
                fields: {
                    channelname:{ editable: false}
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // create a subgrid for the current detail row, getting territory data for this employee
    detailRow.find(".subgrid").kendoGrid({
        columns: [
            { title: "Channel Name", field: "channelname"},
            { command: "destroy", title: "&nbsp;", width: "100px" }
        ],
        dataSource: subDS,
        editable: true,
        remove: function(e) {
            //alert("Removing:" + e.model.channelid);
            var xmlhttp2;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp2=new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                xmlhttp2=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp2.open("POST","data/chMove.php",true);
            xmlhttp2.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp2.send("channel="+e.model.channelid);
        }
    });
```

The most important is set your subgrid to be editable( I don't set the attribute before),

and the model of id can let you use in your data("results").

And I also show my trick to connect to PHP side :)

Then you can handle the server side as usual:

(in chMove.php)

```
$channel=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["channel"]);
```

It takes me a lot of time to deal with it, I hope it is helpful.